# Excel 2010 logic conditions vs. '#VALUE!'

Tags: excel-2010

I would like to do logic against the return value of '#VALUE!' in Excel.

**Setup:** Let's say `A1 = "Fu"` and `A2 = "Bar"`.  `A3 = A1 - A2` will give me the `#VALUE!` Value Error.

I would like to do logic such as `IF( (A1 - A2) != "#VALUE!", Do This, Else Do This)`.  If that expression is not allowed, then I can settle for `IF( A3 != "#VALUE!", Do This, Else Do This)`.

My question:  Is this even possible?  Can you write logic against an Excel Value Error response?

Thanks in advance for any tips/tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`IFERROR`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/is-functions-HP005209147.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211) function.

```
IF(ISERROR(A1-A2), DOTHIS, DOTHAT))
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for.  I appreciate the help!